# Can I make ipython exit from the calling code?

Tags: python, ipython

I have some code like this:

```
form IPython import embed
for item in my_item_list:
    embed()
```

If I then run this program with

```
python my_example_program.py
```

on the first iteration through the loop I get put into an ipython shell and can inspect `item` and the environment as I would like to.

On quitting ipython the loop resumes and then I can inspect the next `item` and the environment as you would expect.

Is there a way for me to quit this code from within ipython (so that I am returned to a shell prompt). in any way short of opening another shell and killing the process?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's a [`%kill_embedded`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/api/generated/IPython.terminal.embed.html#IPython.terminal.embed.EmbeddedMagics.kill_embedded) command in IPython.
It doesn't put you directly back to the shell prompt, but it skips the other embed instances.

```
from IPython import embed

for item in range(5):
    print 'embedding', item
    embed()
```

And here's the output:

```
 $ python my_example_program.py
embedding 0
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 13 2014, 22:30:33)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: print item
0

In [2]: ^D

embedding 1
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 13 2014, 22:30:33)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [2]: %kill_embedded
Are you sure you want to kill this embedded instance (y/n)? [y/N]  y
This embedded IPython will not reactivate anymore once you exit.

In [3]: print item
1

In [4]:

embedding 2
embedding 3
embedding 4
 $
```

*UPD (06.03.2016):* Seems that the `%kill_embedded` feature is kind of broken in IPython 4.0; you can use `%exit_raise` which will raise an exception and return back to the shell.

Comment: skipping the other embed instances is exactly what I wanted, thank you.

Comment: What exactly did you do in the last input, just a regular CTRL+D? I'm trying to reproduce this example in IPython 4.0, but I always have to go through all `embed`s in the loop. Looks like `%kill_embedded` actually has no effect.

Comment: @bluenote10 Seems so :\ `%exit_raise` works in that case - it throws an exception and returns you right to the shell.

Comment: hm strange, I'm getting `ERROR: Line magic function `%exit_raise` not found.`

Comment: @bluenote10 That could have been because `%exit_raise` was added in 4.1 according to the [issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/9150). `%kill_embedded` works fine in IPython 5.1.0