# How to abort python script from IPython (console)

Tags: python, interactive

I'm using `embed()` from IPython (console), to interact with my script. Whenever I press **CTRL+D** it exits the interactive mode and proceeds to the next commends following the `embed()` call.

How do I **abort** the complete python script avoiding it from going to further commands after `embed()` from the interactive python?

What I have tried:

**CTRL+C** : only cancels my current command in the IPython

**CTRL+D** : leaves the  IPython and proceeds to the next commands in my script

**Typing exit()** : same as CTRL+D

Here is a sample script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from IPython import embed

print 'hello world'
embed()
print 'I dont want to reach here if I decide to quit from the IPython terminal!'
```

Comment: Are you speaking about iPython notebook? Or just the iPython console ?

Comment: I don't know about that. How do I check this?

Comment: @rkioki How are you launching iPython ?

Comment: @user312016 I simply make my script executable and type ./script.py. I use #!/usr/bin/env python in its header.

Comment: This answer on stackoverflow should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453165/can-i-make-ipython-exit-from-the-calling-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to nuke the process ID from the IPython session:

```
$ python test_embed.py
hello world
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, May 28 2015, 17:04:42)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import os

In [2]: os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)
Killed: 9
```

**EDIT:** Looks like sending SIGQUIT with `Ctrl-\` will also terminate the script entirely.

Comment: This definitely works, but I wonder if there is any easier shortcut.

Comment: `Ctrl-\` is what I was looking for! Thanks perfect.